# Create async task from sync method in python

Tags: python, c#, async-await, python-asyncio

There is a method In C# [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) that accepts delegate as parameter and returns task that can be awaited.

Is there such thing in Python asyncio?

I need to wrap a sync block of code to async task.

Comment: There is something like this in Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: It would be good if you told us the reason why you want to do this.  A useful rule of thumb is that if the sync block of code has blocking I/O the solution is to use a second thread.  If the sync block of code is CPU-intensive and requires a long time to execute, the solution is to use a second Process.

Answer (score -2):

There is something like this in Python

Python docs. for ex:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

for ex:

```
import asyncio

async def print_number():
   print(1)

async def main():
   task = asyncio.create_task(print_number())
   await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: So how to wrap a sync method to task? I guess there should be a method similar to Task.Run(()=>{}).

Comment: Yes, the method is the same

Comment: as far as I understand asyncio.run is used for other purpose: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html?highlight=run#asyncio.run

Comment: There is also use for other purposes, but it is also used for the question you asked.

Comment: asyncio.run doesn't return awaitable task, you can't write 'await asyncio.run(...)'

Comment: import asyncio

async def print_number():
    print(1)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(print_number())
    await task

asyncio.run(main())